# How to write a WHERE clause with the '=' operator using db_select()?

Tags: 7, database

I have MySQL query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM `field_revision_field_innostream_state`
WHERE `field_innostream_state_tid` =187
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How to write a WHERE condition within db_select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db_select('field_revision_field_innostream_state', 'innostream')
  ->fields('innostream')
  ->condition('innostream.field_innostream_state_tid', 187, '=')
  ->range(0,30)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
```

Comment: it provides me no of rows having field_innostream_state_tid - 187, now thing is how to get count of these rows ?

Comment: I did this and get counts:
$qry = db_select('field_revision_field_innostream_state', 'innostream')
        ->fields('innostream')
        ->condition('innostream.field_innostream_state_tid', 187, '=')
        ->execute()->rowCount();

Comment: I have add another conditons as required:
$qry = db_select('field_revision_field_innostream_state', 'innostream')
        ->fields('innostream')
        ->condition('entity_id', $value)
        ->condition('innostream.field_innostream_state_tid', 187, '=')
        ->execute()->rowCount();

Comment: I always confused with conditions. Thanks a lot...!

Comment: @RajenderRajan you’re welcome !!